# Where can I find exercises on double sums?

Tags: reference-request, summation, soft-question

Does anyone know of a resource containing lots and lots of exercises involving double sums: finding closed form expressions, manipulating indices, etc.?

Comment: In general, the request " TOPIC + PRACTICE TEST+PDF" sends back useful answers